# User creation form - updating and creating - using different inputs. Angular 2+

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, ionic-framework, angular2-forms

I am creating a form. This form has two purposes. If the user selects create a user, the password inputs appear. If the user edit's a user, then the password inputs do not appear. Due to my validation, I had to create two separate formgroups. (creationForm / editForm). The issue is I can't use a ternary operation on (form [formGroup]), unsure how I can tell my view that it needs to operate on the certain form.

The reason why I have to switch on formgroups is that if I want to edit a user and try to submit, the form is expecting some sort of validation on the password input field as it would be just one formgroup to draw from. Hope this helps!

p.s not displaying validations etc.. in typescript, not relevant for this question. Thanks!

Ts

```
ngOnInit(){

 this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        userName: this.userName,
      })

      this.creationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        userName: this.userName,
        password: this.password,
        passwordConfirm: this.passwordConfirm,

      },{
        validator: ConfirmPasswordValidator.MatchPassword // your validation method
      })

}
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="(editUserFlag ? editForm : creationForm)" (ngSubmit)="submit()" novalidate>
        <div class="edit-wrapper">
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col col-12 class="edit-wrapper__outercol">
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col col-12>
                      <app-field-error-display [displayError]="isFieldValid('userName')" errorMsg="Username is required"></app-field-error-display>
                      <input [(ngModel)]="muserName" formControlName="userName" placeholder="Username" class="form-field" required [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('userName')"/>
                  </ion-col>
                  <ion-col col-12 *ngIf="!editUserFlag">
                      <app-field-error-display [displayError]="isFieldValid('password')"errorMsg="Password does not meet criteria"></app-field-error-display>
                      <p class="password-class">Password must contain three of the following: Capital Letters, Lower Case Letters, Numbers, Special Characters and must be 8 characters in length.</p>
                      <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="mpassword" formControlName="password" class="form-field" placeholder="Password" required [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('password')"/>
                  </ion-col>
                  <ion-col col-12 *ngIf="!editUserFlag">
                      <app-field-error-display [displayError]="isFieldValid('passwordConfirm')" errorMsg="Match Password"></app-field-error-display>
                      <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="mpasswordConfirm" formControlName="passwordConfirm" class="form-field" placeholder="Confirm Password" required [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('passwordConfirm')"/>
                  </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
          <button full ion-button class="edit-wrapper__button"><span *ngIf="editUserFlag">Update</span><span *ngIf="!editUserFlag">Create</span></button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: You could pass the `editUserFlag` parameter to your validator. In the validator ignore when `editUserFlag` is true.

Answer (score 1):

No need of two forms. You can use only one form for both create and update. Just need to change the validations. For example,

```
ngOnInit(){
this.form= this.formBuilder.group({
    userName: [this.userName],
    password: [this.password],
    passwordConfirm: this.passwordConfirm,

  },{
    validator: ConfirmPasswordValidator.MatchPassword // your validation method
  })
```

}

```
onCreateUser(){
  this.form.controls["password"].setValidators([Validators.required]);
  this.form.controls["password"].updateValueAndValidity();
  this.form.controls["passwordConfirm"].setValidators([Validators.required]);
  this.form.controls["passwordConfirm"].updateValueAndValidity();
}

onUpdateUser(){
  this.form.controls["password"].setValidators(null);
  this.form.controls["password"].updateValueAndValidity();
  this.form.controls["passwordConfirm"].setValidators(null);
  this.form.controls["passwordConfirm"].updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

You can call these methods based on your scenario dynamically.